# Find a number $a$ such that the two curves are orthogonal trajectories of each other.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm learning implicit differentiation and this is one of the problems in the exercises section of my textbook:

[image]

For two curves to be orthogonal projectors of each other, they are perpendicular at every intersection. By differentiating both equations I get
$$
\frac{d}{dx}[(x+c)^{-1}]=-\frac{1}{(x+c)^2}\\
\frac{d}{dx}[a(x+k)^{\frac{1}{3}}]=\frac{a}{3(x+k)^\frac{2}{3}}
$$

I believe that my goal is to find a number $a$ such that
$$
\frac{a}{3(x+k)^\frac{2}{3}}=(x+c)^2
$$
Since for two curves to be perpendicular at a point the slope of one must be the negative reciprocal of the other, which is exactly what is happening the equation above. The only thing I need help with is where to start tackling this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also want the curves to intersect. For that (assuming that $a \neq 0$),
$$\frac{1}{x+c}=a(x+k)^{\frac{1}{3}} \implies (x+k)^{\frac{1}{3}}(x+c)=\frac{1}{a}.$$
The last equation you obtained (via slope) can now be written as:
$$\frac{a}{3}=\frac{1}{a^2}.$$
Solve for $a$.